# Познавательный программный код

Tags: php, javascript

Многие пишут "посоветуйте книгу по программированию", но читать исходники на порядок интереснее, поэтому:

> **Посоветуйте познавательный код**

1. Переписанные стандартные функции, которые на порядок быстрее, качественнее, менее прожорлевее и т.д.
2. Использованы "хитрые" уловки по обходу той или иной проблемы, ошибки и т.д.
3. Просто красивый для программиста код, приятно читаемый

Интересующие языки: PHP, JS, Perl, C#, C++, Delphi/Pascal, но можно и другие )

Comment: первые два пункта обычно называются "костыли"

Comment: @eicto и все равно, они иногда необходимы ) если нестандартные решения не справляются

Comment: @eicto, по поводу пункта 1 не соглашусь (не в контексте php, а более глобально)

Answer (score 3):

The *Guardian* выложила весь свой *frontend*  в открытый доступ. Все это можно посмотреть на [github](https://github.com/guardian/frontend). Вроде как там много интересного.

Answer (score 0):

Можно найти программы-игры, где нужно дописать или изменить код лоя прохождения уровня. Замечательно подходит для изучения тонкостей языка.